# List of Eclipse pictogram?

Tags: eclipse, image

After some time of working with Eclipse - Java Enterprise, STS etc. I found enormous quantity of icons, pictures, pictogram etc. Does is possible to find list of all to use in work?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short, it is not possible to do. The longer explanation is, that every plug-in of Eclipse can contribute additional icons, and they are keyed using freeform string identifiers.

However, if you want to reuse some icons (and the EPL licence of Eclipse permits it), a non-complete list of icons is available at http://eclipse-icons.i24.cc/